# PHP foreach over an array of objects

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, iteration

I'm trying to use a foreach loop for an array of objects.  Inside of the BeginBattle() method I want to iterate through all of the objects and increment their played count automatically.  Unfortunately, the web browser shows I have an error: **Fatal error: Call to a member function BattleInitiated() on a non-object in /nfs/c05/h01/mnt/70299/domains/munchkinparty.neededspace.net/html/Battle.php on line 75**

Any ideas?

```
<?php
/* 
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/**
 * Description of Battle
 *
 * @author joshualowry
 */
class Battle {
    /**
     *
     * @var <type>
     */
    private $_players;
    /**
     *
     * @var <type>
     */
    private $_battleInProgress;
    /**
     *
     */
    public function Battle(){
        $this->_players = array();
        $this->_battleInProgress = FALSE;

    }
    /**
     *
     * @param <type> $player
     * @return <type>
     */
    public function AddPlayer($player){
        if(!$this->_battleInProgress)
            $this->_players[] = $player;
        else
            return;
            //Spit some error
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param <type> $player
     * @return <type>
     */
    public function BattleWon($player){
        if($player != NULL)
            $player->BattleWon();
        else
            return;
            //Spit some error
    }
    /** GetPlayerByName Get the player's object by the player's name field.
     *
     * @param <type> $playerName
     * @return <type>
     */
    public function GetPlayerByName($playerName){
        foreach($this->_players as &$player) {
            if($player->GetName() == $playerName)
        return $player;
        }
        return NULL;
    }

    /**
     *
     */
    public function BeginBattle(){
        $this->_battleInProgress = TRUE;
        foreach($this->_players as $player){
        $player->BattleInitiated();
    }
    }
    /**
     *
     */
    public function DisplayCurrentBoard() {
        echo "Name  Alias   Wins    Battles<br/>";
        foreach($this->_players as &$player){
            echo "$player->GetName()    $player->GetAlias() $player->GetWins()  $player->GetBattles()<br/>";
        }
    }

}
?>
```

This is where everything is declared and called:

```
<?php
    include 'Battle.php';
    include 'Person.php';
    include 'Player.php';

    $currentBattle = new Battle();

    $playerA = new Player("JohnnyDanger","John",0,0);
    $playerB = new Player("JoshTheJest","Josh",0,0);
    $PlayerC = new Player("CarbQueen","Nicole",0,0);

    $currentBattle->AddPlayer($playerA);
    $currentBattle->AddPlayer($playerB);
    $currentBattle->AddPlayer($playerC);

    $currentBattle->BeginBattle();
    $currentBattle->BattleWon($currentBattle->GetPlayerByName("Josh"));
    $currentBattle->DisplayCurrentBoard();
?>
```

The Player Class

```
    <?php

    /**
    * Description of Player
    *
    * @author joshualowry
    */
    class Player extends Person {

        private $_alias;
        private $_wins;
        private $_battles;

        public function Player($name, $alias, $wins, $battles) {
            parent::SetName($name);
            $this->_alias = $alias;
            $this->_battles = $battles;

            if($battles == 0) {
                $this->_wins = 0;
            }
            else {
                $this->_wins = $wins;
            }
        }

        protected function SetAlias($value){
            $this->_alias = $value;
        }

        public function GetAlias(){
            return $this->_alias;
        }

        protected function SetBattles($value) {
            $this->_battles = $value;
        }

        public function GetBattles(){
            return $this->_battles;
        }

        protected function SetWins($value) {
            $this->_wins = $value;
        }

        public function GetWins() {
            return $this->_wins;
        }

        public function BattleWon(){
            $this->_wins += 1;
        }

        public function BattleInitiated(){
            $this->_battles += 1;
        }

    }

?>
```

Comment: Show us where AddPlayer is being called.

Comment: What are you passing to AddPlayer()?

Comment: How are you instantiating your `Battle()` object and calling the `AddPlayer()` and the `BeginBattle()` functions?

Comment: Do you have a Player class and a proper constructor [http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php] ?

Comment: @JannieT Your link gives a 404.

Comment: Sorry about the bad link. Try this one: [http://th2.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php]

Comment: So for some reason PlayerC is showing up as NULL...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message indicates that you are trying to all the `BattleInitiated()` method on something that wasn't an object.

Judging from your code, the problem seems to be with this loop, in the `BeginBattle()` method :

```
foreach($this->_players as $player){
    $player->BattleInitiated();
}
```

Which means $player, at least one in your array, is probably not an object ; maybe it's `null`, or an array ?

To know more, you should use `var_dump` to display the content of `$this->_players` before the loop, just to make sure it contains what you expect it to :

```
public function BeginBattle(){
    var_dump($this->_players);
    $this->_battleInProgress = TRUE;
    foreach($this->_players as $player){
        $player->BattleInitiated();
    }
}
```

If `$this->_players` doesn't contain what you expect it to *(and it probably doesn't !)*, you'll then have to find out why...

Considering `$this->_players` is modified by the `AddPlayer()` method, which adds what it receives to the end of the array, I would bet that `AddPlayer()` is called at least once without a correct `$player` as a parameter.

To help with that, you could use `var_dump` on the `$player` being added :

```
public function AddPlayer($player){
    var_dump($player);
    if(!$this->_battleInProgress)
        $this->_players[] = $player;
    else
        return;
        //Spit some error
}
```

If that `var_dump` indicates at least once that `$player` is not an object *(for instance, it's `null`, or an array, or a string, ...)*, that's the cause of your Fatal Error.

Comment: I added some code above, but the third player, PlayerC, is null once it is added using AddPlayer... any ideas?

Comment: I just realized I was adding $PlayerC not $playerC.

Your answer helped me find the error.  

I added a check when a player is added to the battle to see if it is a 'Player'.  Now NULL vars and other types will not be added.

Comment: Glad to see you found what was causing the problem :-) And thanks for explaning it :-)

Answer (score 1):

don't you see it??

it's all because of a small typo:

```
 $playerA = new Player("JohnnyDanger","John",0,0);
    $playerB = new Player("JoshTheJest","Josh",0,0);
    $PlayerC = new Player("CarbQueen","Nicole",0,0);

    $currentBattle->AddPlayer($playerA);
    $currentBattle->AddPlayer($playerB);
    $currentBattle->AddPlayer($playerC);
```

declared: $_P_layerC
used: $_p_layerC

correct that and you're good to go

Comment: Thanks for looking back at this.  As you will see my comment on the accepted answer stating that the poster's tips helped me to find the typo and also helped me to realize that I needed to validate the entries before adding them.

Answer (score 0):

Your `$player` variable is either **null** or not an **Object** of the **type** you want it to be.

`PlayerObject` is what ever your class name for player is.

For example

```
$battle=new Battle();
$player1=new PlayerObject();
$player2="player";
$battle->AddPlayer($player1);
$battle->AddPlayer($player2);
$battle->BeginBattle();
```

when you call `BeginBattle()` the `$player1->BattleInitiated();` will be successful but the `$player2->BattleInitiated()` will give you the fatal error and stop your code from running. same if `$player2` was null, an integer or something that is not `PlayerObject`.